# Sort an array and store its indices in another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like `array = [9,0,0,1,0,5,1,3,1]` . I want to sort this array and get the indices of the sorted array elements as another array.

ie. after sorting:

```
sortedArray = [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,5,9]
indexArray = [1,2,4,3,6,8,7,5,0]
```

Is there any way to get the indices of the sorted array?

Comment: I don't understand what is indexArray in your exemple

Comment: @dan So in another 4.5 seconds you'll provide the second half of the answer...?

Comment: You'll probably need an intermediary data format that keeps value and index and sort this based on value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var arr = [9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 3, 1];

  var _temp = arr.map(function(item, index) {
    return {
      index: index,
      value: item
    }
  });

  console.log(_temp)

  _temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
    if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  console.log(_temp)

  console.log(_temp.map(function(item) {
    return item.value
  }))
  console.log(_temp.map(function(item) {
    return item.index
  }))
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no index-value association in an array, you'll need to establish that first:

```
var tmp = array.map(function (val, i) { return [i, val]; });
// [[0, 9], [1, 0], ..]
```

Then you sort it:

```
tmp.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
```

Then you extract the indices and/or values again:

```
var indexArray = tmp.map(function (i) { return i[0]; });
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
var array = [9,0,0,1,0,5,1,3,1];
var indexArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    indexArray.push(i);
}

var sortedArray = array.sort();

console.log(sortedArray);
console.log(indexArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Having the sortedArray, you can loop over the array, and use the `indexOf()` Method to get the index of the each element of the sorted array in the old array. For example.

```
sortedArray.forEach(function(ele){
  indexArray.push(oldArray.indexOf(ele));
});
```